# jQuery Collapsible Plugin: How to toggle Open all/Close all

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, toggle

http://github.com/juven14/Collapsible
http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/collapsible.html

Instead of the two links "Open All" and "Close All" I want only one link toggling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jquery.collapsible.js` API comes with a `toggle` method:

> These are the methods available from the plugin:

- cssClose - class assigned when closed
- collapsed - returns 'true' if element is collapsed
- **toggle - toggle collapsible state**
- open - open a collapsible
- close - close a collapsible

> -Via "Plugin Methods" on the [page OP provided](http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/collapsible.html)

Mimicking the style found on the demo page:

```
function toggle() {
    $('.page_collapsible').collapsible('toggle');
}

$('#toggle').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    toggle();
});
```

Comment: Mea culpa! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a variable, like `var open = false;`.
Everytime, the one link is clicked on, check whether `open` is `true` or `false`. Now you know, which action should come - Open all if `!open`, Close all if `open`.
Don't forget to change the value `open = !open` each time, so that the action changes too.

Comment: I just realized, that this method comes to its limits, if you manually open all sections separately and then click "Toggle all".

Comment: Yes it does, you would have to check the situation everytime the user collapses or expands an element and when all elements have the same state, change the `open` as well.
So, couzzi's answer is much better.